# How do I localize admin-ajax.php that is used in Ajax Load More - Infinite Scroll?

Tags: plugins, ajax

I would like to localise the ajaxurl for the plugin Ajax Load More - Infinite Scroll:

```
/* <![CDATA[ */
var alm_localize = {“ajaxurl”:”http:\/\/siteurl\/test\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php”,”alm_nonce”:”0dge8w13b3″,”pluginurl”:”http:\/\/homeurl\/test\/wp-content\/plugins\/ajax-load-more”,”scrolltop”:”false”};
/* ]]> *
```

How can this be achieved?

Thank you

EDIT1:

I have come up with this:

```
 $localiser = array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ),
      );
      wp_localize_script( "ajax-load-more", "alm_localize", $localiser );
```

How do I register the plugin js? In Load More case, what do I have to register? the main ajax-load-more.js in /core/js in the plugin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [**wp_localize_script**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)

```
$myData = array(
    'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
);
wp_localize_script( "myScript", "alm_localize", $myData );
```

**NOTE:** **`myScript`** should be the handle of a script which has been registered using `wp_register_script`

Comment: what is the handle for Ajax Load More?

Comment: handle for ajax load more?

Comment: yeah, I am looking at the plugin and I am not sure what is the handle for the ajax load more. My difficulty is to understand what I should call. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think I got it, the script should be ajax-load-more for that plugin

Comment: Do I need to register the actual ajax-load-more.js?